# embed video is hiding in bootstrap mobile view

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootswatch

i am using latest version of **bootstrap and bootswatch united theme** , to create and learn a normal website. the website is currently live on this link [live site](http://loversorlosers.com/) , and there is an embed in right side as you can see. i am using asp.net mvc as view engine but thats just it.

the code for videos page is on jsfiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/v3bjzoej/` as **SO** doesnt allow it because of XSS problems.

```
<section class="col-lg-6 pull-right">
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/116351996" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</section>
```

the same is happening on index page `http://jsfiddle.net/pw1zyypf/`

i am having troubles with posting complete code on fiddle maybe due to so many mvc objects in it. I know its related to css issues, but a real help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this `col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6` to the `section` which have video `iframe`

```
<section class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right">
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe src=""></iframe>
  </div>
</section>
```

- `col-sm-6` - for Small devices Tablets (≥768px) (half)
- `col-md-6` - for Medium devices Desktops (≥992px) (half)
- `col-xs-12` - Extra small devices Phones (<768px) (full)

Comment: thanks that worked like a charm , also do you know any good bootstrap learning platform where i can learn things in details. as of now i am still using tables on many places where i cant fix the format , which is very bad for seo purposes as i was told.

Comment: i learnt from http://getbootstrap.com/ and whenever m stuck i just search on google most of the answers are already answered

Comment: i tried using bootsnips but it was having a different approach. i will see the site you suggested now.